# How small may the discriminant of an $S_d$-field be?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, discriminant

In every degree $d$, the Galois closure of the typical number field has the maximal possible Galois group $S_d$. Denote by $f(d)$ the least absolute value of a discriminant of an $S_d$-field of degree $d$. My question is what is provably known about the asymptotic behavior of this function $f(d)$, and in particular, whether or not it is known to be exponentially bounded in the degree $d$.

Regarding heuristics (I would be interested in good ones, too), let me only mention that the global function fields model, when appropriately formulated, does have an exponentially growing $f(d)$, but that this is probably a poor guide in this type of question. (For instance, since the function field model admits a fully explicit and monogenic construction, which is conjectured to not exist in the case of number fields: the root discriminant of an integer irreducible polynomial is widely believed to approach infinity as the degree grows.)

As everyone knows, the Golod-Shafarevich towers give plenty of examples of number fields with an exponentially bounded discriminant, but those by their construction have solvable Galois groups, and are irrelevant in my question.

*Added example*. It is easily seen that $f(d) < d^d$, but this crude bound, I suppose, would be far from the truth. To see this bound, recall that Selmer proved that the trinomial $t^d - t - 1$ is irreducible with maximal Galois group $S_d$, and of discriminant $\pm( d^d - (1-d)^{d-1})$, which gives the bound, at least for $d$ odd (and the slightly weaker bound $f(d) < 2d^d$ in general).

Comment: Not sure this is in the direction you want, but I think Bhargava-Shankar-Wang's paper "Squarefree values of polynomial discriminants I", https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09806 proves a lower bound for the number of $S_d$ number fields of discriminant $<X$ that they conjecture to be essentially sharp. (And they discuss various related results.)

Comment: @TimDokchitser: Thank you, in these results though they assume that the degree $d$ is fixed, and don't bother with writing down implied constants depending on $d$. Presumably the growing degrees and small discriminate case is not as well understood. On the other hand, the question would be solved if there existed an $\mathrm{Spec} \, O_{K,S}$ whose etale fundamental group (group of the maximal unramified outside $S$ extension of $K$) is complicated enough to contain an $S_d$-quotient for each $d = 1, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Why is this enough? There exist extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with unbounded root discriminant.

Comment: @Aurel: Sorry, due to the word count limitation of the comment window I omitted to state that $S$ is a finite set of places of some number field $K$, and that $O_{K,S}$ is here the ring of $S$-integers of $K$ (not a localization). You are right that my notation was ambiguous at best.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov That was my understanding of your notation, but I don't see why a family of $S_d$-extensions of $K$ unramified outside a fixed $S$ should have bounded root discriminant.

Comment: You are right. Take $S = \emptyset$: I should have simply said $\mathrm{Spec} \, O_K$.